# How to choose the duplicates among these 4 highly voted questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

When searching for an answer today I came across these four questions. They all basically ask the same thing and all have answers that solved my problem.

1. [Hide remove separator line if UITableViewCells are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460772/how-to-hide-remove-separator-line-if-cells-are-empty)
2. [Can I force a UITableView to hide the separator between empty cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633966/can-i-force-a-uitableview-to-hide-the-separator-between-empty-cells)
3. [Eliminate extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-ios)
4. [How to remove empty cells in UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520185/how-to-remove-empty-cells-in-uitableview)

In choosing a model Q&A that I can point the others as duplicates of, I know I shouldn't necessarily choose the oldest one. Things I look for are

- A succinct clear question (an image can help with that in situations like this)
- A good title
- Good answers at the top of the list
- Number of votes

Question 1 above might be the clearest question because it has an image. I can see at a glance that it matches my problem. But it doesn't have the best title and the top answers aren't that good.

I'm leaning toward [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview) because it had a good top answer and is also a community wiki so anyone can feel free to update it in the future. However, the question itself isn't very clear. (All that extra code is just noise.)

What do other people think?

### Update

I replaced the unnecessary code in [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview) with an image that illustrates the problem. I think it is a much better question now that is worthy of marking all others as duplicates of. I only hope that the OP will not mind my heavy edit.

I voted to close [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460772/how-to-hide-remove-separator-line-if-cells-are-empty) and [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520185/how-to-remove-empty-cells-in-uitableview) as duplicates. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633966/can-i-force-a-uitableview-to-hide-the-separator-between-empty-cells) was already closed by Josh Caswell.

Comment: Are you expecting us to vote?

Comment: I would like some sort of input before I choose which ones are duplicates.

Comment: Can you edit Question 3 to include the image from Question 1 and remove the extra code?

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633966/can-i-force-a-uitableview-to-hide-the-separator-between-empty-cells is just a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-ios, so that one's a no-brainer. Would be nice to clean out the answer as well, but that requires a mod.

Comment: By the way, old questions like this always have a ton of duplicate answers by people either unwilling to read or just hoping for some stray upvotes. Anyone who's looking at this, please help moderate this superfluous material.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good candidate for a [*question merge*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119518#119518). Flag one of the posts (use the custom moderator flag) and explain the situation. I agree that question 1 is the best *question*, but the screenshot is a little outdated.

Comment: Won't that make a huge list of duplicate answers? Or am I not understanding merging?

Comment: @Suragch yes, it will, and no, I don't think it will be necessary. Merging is when two duplicated questions gathered diametrically different answers and all of them good answers that apply to both questions.

Comment: So since the answers were all basically the same in this case, this probably wouldn't be such a good candidate for merging.